# YUI Compressor and .NET Apps

Tags: .net, optimization, process, build

I want to use YUI Compressor (the original) and use it as part of typical MS build processes (Visual Studio 2008, MSBuild).

Does anyone have any guidance or thoughts on this? For example, good ways for incorporating into project, what to do with existing CSS and JS references, and the like.

I am happy to hear on the benefits of YUI Compressor .NET and alternatives but I'm more interested in use of the original.

Thanks
Scott

Comment: Asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295395/minify-merge-javascript-minify-css-on-visual-studio-build

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use both. The YUI compressor is command-line, and easy to integrate into any build process. I got it running in rake with no problems.

It's probably most common to perform the javascript/css compression in-place when you deploy. That way you don't have to update JS references. But I'm using another method on my site. I have the compressed files created as `*-min.js`, etc. To include a script or css file on my page, I call a server-side method:

```
<%= ScriptSrc("~/assets/myscript.js") %>
<%= LinkSrc("~/assets/main.css") %>
```

These methods do the following:

1. Expand the app-relative path
2. add a version string to the end (for cache invalidation)
3. choose between the full script and a minified version depending on whether we are in debug mode or not.

In debug mode, `ScriptSrc` might output something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stage.myapp.com/assets/myscript.js?v=1.2" ></script>
```

but in production it would load the minified version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stage.myapp.com/assets/myscript-min.js?v=1.2" ></script>
```

One of the benefits of this is that I can switch between the full and minified versions just by changing the `web.config`, which can aid debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Please reference this article: [How to use Visual Studio's Post-build Event with YUI Compressor for .NET](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Visual%20Studio%20Post-build%20Event%20example)

Answer (score 1):

Because the YUI Compressor is simply a command line tool, you could call it as part of a Pre or Post Build action. (If you delve deep enough into MSBuild, you can let it run only when the files have changed, speeding up your regular builds; VS is pretty lenient when it comes to customized MSBuild actions in your project file.)

You could use Gabe's answer as a guideline on how to develop using such a setup; you could also during the `Render` of, say, a master page translate all non-minified url's in your `<head>` with minified url's (a little tricky though, as `<script>` tags will show up in the middle of the `Text` property of `LiteralControl`s).

Answer (score 0):

I've used compiler directives for my script includes- for example (in the master page);

```
  ...
  <% #if RELEASE %>
    <script src="Scripts/combined.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <% #else %>
    <script src="Scripts/myscript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/myscript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <% #endif %>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in the build process my various .js files are combined all into one conbined.min.js file.